# How to set your sensitive data in the application code when creating ADO.NET Model?d some tag a

Tags: c#, security, entity-framework, model, connection

I am creating a model for a database and was curious at the following statement in the ADO.NET Entity Model wizard where you have the options of choosing Yes or No as where to store sensitive data -

> "No, exclude sensitive data from the connection string. I will set it
>   in my application code."

I have never used this option and just wanted to find out if I did where I would have to specify my sensitive data. Any ideas?

Comment: Very good question! I'd like to know that too.

Answer (score 8):

Set the connection string argument of the Model constructor:

```
MyEntities1 db = new MyEntities1 ("metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=';Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDb;User ID=user1;Password=myPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True';");
```

Answer (score 2):

Create Encrypted DLL to hold connection string

Modify the constructor of the entities

```
 // Separate Encrypted DLL file
 public static class secureData()
 {
    public static string ConString = @"Data Source=YOUR_SERVER;Initial 
    Catalog=YOUR_DB;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=YOUR_USER;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD";
 }


 public sampleDBEntities() : base("name=sampleDBEntities")
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =  secureData.ConString ;
    }
```

Comment: Well, this gets it out of web.config, but my understanding is that it's pretty much just as visible in obfuscated C# code, no?

Comment: Yes. But you can use the **encryption techniques** to protect your connection strings.

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard Alternatively, you can write some code to read the password from somewhere more secure.

Comment: @VigneshRaja-TheRealStar any link for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have used in the past, although many will argue its unsecure to store plain text passwords in your source files. There are methods to secure this by encrypting your connection strings;

```
public db_entity()
            : base("name=db_entity")
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString= "server=localhost;user id=<USERNAME>;Password=<PASSWORD.;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=<DB_NAME>";            
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

It's the username and password for connection string. If you do not have them in the config file, you'll have to provide them when creating the data context.